# Install Axios module to work use with Testcafe (in Docker container)

Tags: axios, testcafe

We want to use for E2E tests Testcafe with Axios module. We use standard Docker image Testcafe with installed Axios using

```
npm install -g axios
```

Test file is in folder `/tests`.

After several unsuccessful try I get inside the container and try to start test manually:

running test with command
testcafe firefox:headless /tests/AA_API_create_user.js
returs error:

```
ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to the following error:

Error: Cannot find module 'axios'
Require stack:
- /tests/AA_API_create_user.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/lib/compiler/test-file/formats/es-next/compiler.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/lib/compiler/compilers.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/lib/compiler/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/lib/runner/bootstrapper.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/lib/runner/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/lib/testcafe.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/lib/index.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/lib/cli/cli.js
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/testcafe/lib/cli/index.js
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tests/AA_API_create_user.js:3:1)`
```

if I try list of modules: `npm list -g`:

```
/usr/local/lib
+-- asynckit@0.4.0
+-- axios@1.6.2
+-- combined-stream@1.0.8
+-- delayed-stream@1.0.0
+-- follow-redirects@1.15.3
+-- form-data@4.0.0
+-- mime-db@1.52.0
+-- mime-types@2.1.35
+-- proxy-from-env@1.1.0
-- testcafe@3.4.0
```

Axios is found if I install npm module to the same dir as the tests:

```
cd /tests
npm install axios
```

But this not solve my problem, because the folder with tests is needed to mount outside container. Any idea how to install Axios to properly work with Testcafe in Docker container?

Comment: Just guessing to stimulate ideas - it seems like the global `node_modules` is out of scope for a command running in `/test/`. Might [npm linking](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link) help after the container has been started?

Comment: This bit sounds relevant: "Next, in some other location, `npm link` package-name will create a symbolic link from globally-installed `package-name` to `node_modules/` of the current folder."

Comment: Another idea: if this is in CI instead of a dev container, you could forego the mount volume, and dynamically copy the tests into `/test/` when the container is first started. Then you can install `axios` into this folder without having to install them globally.

Comment: strange - I try npm link at the axios folder and get error - 52 warn tarball tarball data for axios@file:axios (null) seems to be corrupted. Trying again.
53 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 1ms
54 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 1ms
55 timing command:link Completed in 191ms
56 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/axios/axios/package.json'          .../axios/axios/... is problem

Comment: I wonder if you have the mount point in `/tests` that any symlinking in there is going to act weird, since the link will exist in the host/volume, and try to point to somewhere in the container.

Comment: What `pwd` do you have when you try linking? From my quoted bit, it sounds like you should be in `/tests` in a container shell. (You won't be able to do this on the host, even if `/tests` maps to an on-host folder).

Comment: install axios to /tests and try to create npm link - make this err: npm ERR! Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.  PWD /tests

Comment: At the first try to npm link - the PWD was /usr/local/lib/node_modules/axios

Comment: OK. Is this for CI? If so perhaps you can try my suggestion of not having a mount/volume.

Answer (score -1):

Node js modules referenced in tests should be located in the mapped host directory or its subdirectories. Otherwise, they could not be accessed from the container. Alternatively, you can share a drive to reach it from Docker containers. For more information, see the [Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/get-started/).